# How do I check to see if it's safe to call compute on Dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

Currently my PC it's freezing while I'm trying to calculate the log1p to entire Column a large dataset (4GB ~ 125 Million of rows) when I run this:

```
df_train = dd.read_csv('data/train.csv')
s = df_train.unit_sales.map_partitions(np.log1p)
s.compute()
```

So, How Can I handle know if it's secure to compute a function?

Answer (score 4):

Note that when you call `.compute()` you are converting your lazy Dask dataframe into an in-memory Pandas dataframe.  Your result (in this case `s.compute()`) should fit comfortably into memory.  If you want you can call `s.memory_usage().compute()` to see how large your result will be when computed.

Instead, it's common to only compute small results or to write large results back to disk with methods like `.to_csv()` or `.to_parquet()`.  If you are on a cluster and want to use distributed memory then you probably want to use `persist` rather than `compute`.

Comment: When I run `s.memory_usage().compute()` the result is: 1003982640, this value means size of bytes?

Comment: Yes, see either [Dask dataframe API documentation](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.memory_usage) or [Pandas API documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html) for more information